# Advice on roleplaying an angry character without being a jerk

Tags: roleplaying

I've made a character whose anger has become a steadily increasing problem and whose quest revolves around managing that anger. He would be a good person just the anger is becoming a problem.

I don't know how to play such a character without being too unpleasant to my party members or not angry enough to be true to the persona.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to get the best of a Q&A site.  It will be helpful to indicate which game system you are playing, since some games have hard coded mechanics for things like this, and other games are a little less mechanically controlled that way.  What game are you playing?   It will make for far better, and far more useful, answers if people expert in a particular game can help you with using those game's features to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would make sure that every players know that the anger comes from the character and is a big part of him, not from you the player around the table. That's gonna help everyone to get onboard with the idea.

But you are asking specifically about "how to roleplay it" so I'll jump into that.

### Voice acting

You chose to play something more complicated than most characters. Being able to voice an angry character well would be great fun for you and everyone at the table.

Here's some tips on how it can be done:

- Shouting. Angry people shout. But try not to be too loud, having a player constantly shout can be annoying.
- Prepare "catch phrases". Prepare a string of insults your character would throw at those NPCs that anger him, as part of his bio. Invent swear words he's gonna start spewing sometimes when he gets angry. Make them short and sweet, so you can use them to quickly as a cue for other players to realize your character is starting to get angry.
- Prepare different "levels" of anger. His voice would be different when he is very angry, he'd be a bit more "mellow" when only slightly angry.
- Grumble. Grumble a lot. Be grumpy and show it when you are, by grumbling.

### Narratively describing his bouts of anger

Describe how his face turns red. How he is stomping his feet and gesticulating wildly while he's shouting, spittle forming on his lips. Have him flip a table. Throw his mug across the room. Etc.

Narration is a strong tool. Use it efficiently.

### Alternate between voice acting and narrating his physical actions

Voice: "I WILL KILL YOU, YOU VERMIN EATING SON OF A KOBOLD"

Narration: My character will spit at the feet of the Dragonborn that made him angry and he's giving him the coldest death stare he can muster.

GM: The Dragonborn is very surprised by your reaction and you can see that your reaction is taking him aback and he doesn't know how to react.

Narration: Not even seeing a reaction angers my character even further. You all see him closing his fists as he starts to shake from barely contained anger. His breath is ragged and his face is turning red. Then he says, in a low growling voice dripping with disdain...

Voice: "Oh, NOW you shut up ? You have nothing to say for yourself huh ? GET OUT OF MY FACE YOU SCALY BASTARD !"

Narrating: Then my character is gonna shove him, see if that gets a reaction ...